# SQL Query Help needed for creating fields

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to write a query that has two foreign keys to another table.  I need to look them both up and get the names back from the ID.  I have a query but I am getting each returned as a separate record.

```
SELECT Teams.team_name, Games.ID, Games.game, Games.date, Games.time, Games.team_one, Games.team_two, Games.pts 
FROM Teams, Games 
WHERE Teams.ID = Games.team_one OR Teams.ID = Games.team_two 
ORDER BY Games.ID ASC
```

So Games.team_one and Games.team_two are foreign keys to my Teams table.  I need to get back a record:

Games.ID, Games.game, Games.date, Games.time, Games.team_one, Games.team_two, Team1 Name, & Team Two Name

right now I am receiving two records that are identical except the team_name is different.  How can I create a dynamic field for team_one_name and team_two_name to have looked up based on Games.team_one & Games.team_two and have them part of the same record?

Thanks for your help.

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Using the preferred ANSI style join syntax:

```
SELECT t1.team_name AS team_one_name, 
       t2.team_name AS team_two_name, 
       games.id,
       games.game, 
       games.date,
       games.time, 
       games.team_one,
       games.team_two, 
       games.pts
FROM   games 
INNER JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id = games.team_one 
INNER JOIN teams t2 ON t2.id = games.team_two 
ORDER BY games.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use GROUP BY clause

Comment: Thanks for your help.  If I group on the GameID then I only get one team_name.  How do I get two columns for TeamName so I can have both teams that face off in the event?

Comment: Using a `GROUP BY` to aggregate the data might work but is not the cleanest solution. This just requires two joins to separate teams, using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use aliases to join the table teams twice with different names:

```
 SELECT t1.team_name as   
 team_one_name, t2.team_name as  
 team_two_name, Games.ID,
 Games.game, Games.date,
 Games.time, Games.team_one,
 Games.team_two, Games.pts 
 FROM Teams t1, Teams t2, Games 
 WHERE t1.ID = Games.team_one OR  
   t2.ID = Games.team_two 
 ORDER BY Games.ID ASC
```

Comment: Arrrg!  Thanks!  This makes sense now.  Its been a while.  All good now!

Comment: Should the last or be an and?

Comment: Also, I'd prefer to see ANSI joins here, rather than the joins being done in the `WHERE` clause.